# How can I change one image for another by clicking on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Currently, I can `show/hide` the text I want using the `slideToggle()` method.

Now I have been trying that when doing click, I can also change the image that I have for another one in each click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".txtEachCaracteristica").css('display', 'none');

  $(".txtTituCaracteristica, .arrowBlack").click(function(ev) {
    $(this).next(".txtEachCaracteristica").slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.txtTituCaracteristica {
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15pt;
}

.icon-more {
  height: 18px;
}

p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

<br />

<div id="titu1" class="txtTituCaracteristica">
  <p>Living</p> <img class="icon-more" src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/1600/plus-math.png" />
</div>

<div id="txt1" class="txtEachCaracteristica">Lorem ipsum dolor sit armet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<br>

<div id="titu2" class="txtTituCaracteristica">Hab <img class="icon-more" src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/1600/plus-math.png" /></div>
<div id="txt2" class="txtEachCaracteristica">Lorem ipsum dolor sit armet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<br>
<img class="icon-more" src="https://png.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/1600/minus-math.png" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the image you wish to change is the plus/minus icon...

The trick is to check the `src` attribute value and change it for the other one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".txtEachCaracteristica").css('display', 'none');

    $(".txtTituCaracteristica, .arrowBlack").click(function(ev) {
      $(this).next(".txtEachCaracteristica").slideToggle('slow');
      
      // Change the icon
      var icon = $(this).find(".icon-more");
      if(icon.attr("src")=="https://png.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/1600/minus-math.png"){
        icon.attr("src","https://png.icons8.com/metro/1600/plus-math.png");
      }else{
        icon.attr("src","https://png.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/1600/minus-math.png");
      }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.txtTituCaracteristica {line-height: 2; font-weight: 600;font-size: 15pt;}

.icon-more{height: 18px;}
p {display: inline;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">




<br />

<div id="titu1" class="txtTituCaracteristica">
   <p>Living</p> <img class="icon-more" src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/1600/plus-math.png"/>
</div>

<div id="txt1" class="txtEachCaracteristica">Lorem ipsum dolor sit armet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<br>

<div id="titu2" class="txtTituCaracteristica">Hab <img class="icon-more" src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/1600/plus-math.png"/></div>
<div id="txt2" class="txtEachCaracteristica">Lorem ipsum dolor sit armet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<br> 
<img class="icon-more" src="https://png.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/1600/minus-math.png"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by 'image' you mean the plus/minus icons, then it would be much easier to amend them by toggling a CSS class on the clicked element which defines them in an `:after` pseudo element on a child `span`, something like this:

```js
$(".txtTituCaracteristica").click(function(ev) {
  $(this).toggleClass('open').next(".txtEachCaracteristica").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.txtTituCaracteristica {
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15pt;
}

.txtTituCaracteristica span {
  position: relative;
}

.txtTituCaracteristica span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('https://png.icons8.com/metro/1600/plus-math.png');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  top: 3px;
  right: -25px;
}
.txtTituCaracteristica.open span:after {
  background-image: url('https://png.icons8.com/metro/1600/minus-math.png');
}

.txtEachCaracteristica {
  display: none;
}

.icon-more {
  height: 18px;
}

p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="txtTituCaracteristica">
  <span>Living</span>
</div>
<div class="txtEachCaracteristica">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit armet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div><br />

<div class="txtTituCaracteristica">
  <span>Hab</span>
</div>
<div class="txtEachCaracteristica">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit armet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div><br />
```

Comment: Interesting how the "-" `:after`'s image was not preloaded, there was a loading emptiness till the browser loaded the image resource...

Comment: You're right, it's much simpler the way they comment, thank you very much!

Comment: @ArnellVasquezC no problem, glad to help

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Indeed, but nothing a pre-loaded image can't fix.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yep, or rather a font-icon (instead of .png) PS: this was mainly a tip for OP

Comment: In effect, I must change the image for a font-icon

Comment: Sure, you could do that too. I'd suggest using [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/) in that case

Answer (score -1):

Add following code to your click function:

```
 let image = $(this).find('img')
 image.attr('src','https://png.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/1600/minus-math.png"/')
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".txtEachCaracteristica").css('display', 'none');

    $(".txtTituCaracteristica, .arrowBlack").click(function(ev) {
      $(this).next(".txtEachCaracteristica").slideToggle('slow');
     let expanded = $(this).attr("aria-expanded") === 'true'
     let imgSrc = expanded == true ? 'https://png.icons8.com/metro/1600/plus-math.png"/' : 'https://png.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/1600/minus-math.png"/'
    
     let image = $(this).find('img')
     image.attr('src',imgSrc) 
      $(this).attr("aria-expanded", !expanded)
     
     })
     
});
```

```css
body {
  
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.txtTituCaracteristica {line-height: 2; font-weight: 600;font-size: 15pt;}

.icon-more{height: 18px;}
p {display: inline;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">




<br />

<div id="titu1" class="txtTituCaracteristica" aria-expanded='false'>
   <p>Living</p> <img class="icon-more" src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/1600/plus-math.png"/>
</div>

<div id="txt1" class="txtEachCaracteristica">Lorem ipsum dolor sit armet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<br>

<div id="titu2" class="txtTituCaracteristica">Hab <img class="icon-more" src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/1600/plus-math.png"/></div>
<div id="txt2" class="txtEachCaracteristica">Lorem ipsum dolor sit armet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<br> 
<img class="icon-more" src="https://png.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/1600/minus-math.png"/>
```

UPD: Just added `aria-expanded` attr to html element and some logic to switch icon

Comment: This doesn't seem to toggle the image back to the plus on second click

Comment: @Rory McCrossan You are right. It fixed with some more logic